# Why showUserLocation in GeolocateControl in react-map-gl does not show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I used `GeolocateControl` in my map component to move map to user current location. It works but the `showUserLocation` prop does not work in first render of map. I tried to re-render it with a fake setState but it did not work. What can I do to show the blue circle of user current location in first render?

```
<GeolocateControl
          ref={geoControlRef}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          fitBoundsOptions={{
            zoom: 11,
          }}
          trackUserLocation
          showAccuracyCircle={false}
          showUserLocation
          showUserHeading={geoControlRef?.current && true}
          onGeolocate={onGeoLocate}
          positionOptions={{ enableHighAccuracy: true }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

See the example
https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/geolocate-control#methods
You need to trigger the event as follows:

```
  const geoControlRef = useRef<mapboxgl.GeolocateControl>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        geoControlRef.current?.trigger();
      }, 500);
    });
  }, []);
```

```
        <GeolocateControl
          position="bottom-right"
          ref={geoControlRef}
          showUserLocation={true}
          showAccuracyCircle={true}
          fitBoundsOptions={{ maxZoom: 6 }}
        />
```